# How to use a variable with Range?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use the Rowcount as the second Parameter for the Range.

```
Set R = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Range("N2":R).Value =...
```

How is it possible to use R here as the second Parameter?

Best regards!

Comment: **`Range("N2:N" & R).Value`**

Comment: @Zac I don't think the above will work, R is a range here. Perhaps this will Range("N2:N" & R.Rows.Count).Value =...

Comment: @JK2017: good shout.. I missed that `R` was set as range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can look as a more complicated but is logical:

```
Set R = Range("a1", cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup))
range("N2", cells(r.rows.count, "N")).value=...
```

Step-by-step solution:

```
Set lastA = cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup)
set R = range("A1", lastA)

range("N2", cells(lastA.row, "N")).value = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set R = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Range("N2:" & R.Address).Value =...
```

Answer (score 0):

pls try with below

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Range("N2:N" & r.Rows.Count).Value = "R"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to use "r" just for the second value of the Range, not for the whole

Comment: you want the second value of r range (i.e A2) in N2?

Comment: the solution above is perfectly working, thank you though!

Comment: @Marius, Good to hear. Thanks